# Convert feature to raster, not just shape using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, arctoolbox

I am trying to convert a shapefile into a raster, but ArcGIS gives values only to outside cells, not inside´s, so I get a raster with a hole in the inside with the shape of the feature.

How can I inverse the results?

Comment: If you convert a polyline shapefile to a raster it will generate non-nodata cells only at the locations of the lines. Same goes for point shapefiles. If you want a raster covering the whole enclosed area, you need to have a _polygon_ shapefile and convert that to a raster.

Comment: can you share an image showing your issue?

Comment: I hope you can see it
![This is the image of the raster I obtained][2]

  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe6Si.jpg

So if I undertood correctly I have to transform the polyline into polygon

Answer (score 5):

If you convert a polyline shapefile to a raster it will generate non-nodata cells only at the locations that overlap the lines. Same goes for point shapefiles. 
If you want a raster covering the whole enclosed area, you need to have a polygon shapefile and convert that to a raster, meaning that you have to convert a polyline feature to polygon if that is what you have.